# MYSQL command in JSP code

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp

Hello users of StackExchange,
I need to help in my code, because its funny and I dont know what to do.

I have table SQL "members" there registred over 1000 users.

Im doing web app with login and interface.

Problem? After login to my web app, it show me others registred users data.
(screenshot n.1) = http://s3.postimg.org/t74zj5pyr/V_st_i_ek.jpg

BUT, 
I want to see just data from logged user with session.
Like this picture -> (database table with one registred user) === WORKING fine :-D ---
(screenshot n.2) = http://s30.postimg.org/nyz2jqum9/V_st_i_ek.jpg

So, finally there JSP code:

```
try
                        { 
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+dbName, userId, password);
                        statement=connection.createStatement();

                        //String id_ = request.getParameter("id");
                        //String id_ = session.getSessionContext().equals("id");
                        //String searchPhone = request.getParameter("id");

                        String sql ="SELECT * FROM members WHERE id";

                        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                        while(resultSet.next())
                        {
```

I need something like this

String activeUser = session. "get active connection as user XXXX"

String sql ="SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = '" + activeUser + "'";

Contact: pparik2451@gmail.com
Skype: l2jpsinfo

Comment: Do you know that inserting sql and db code into view(JSP) is bad practice?

Comment: No I dont know. Im new in JSP and Im trying to make web app. What is wrong with SQL command in jsp? 

How to protect  my code?

Comment: Make the code that access the database a servlet rather than JSP.  See the `servlets` tag's info page for some basics on servlets.

Comment: Really I dont know where to check. My second developer left from project. And im novice in web application. Before this web app. I did l2j.
This is my first web app and I dont have teacher. I just searching on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. But as I mentioned above - using such things in JSP is a bad practice

```
String sql ="SELECT * FROM members WHERE id=?";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1, "id value");
ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Ok I copy to my code and restart app.:

http://s11.postimg.org/qely9s5df/V_st_i_ek.jpg

EDIT: it must be WELCOME BACK "username"

Comment: replace "id value"  with the value of user identificator or username. I don't know what id-field containing in your DB. as I understand you need to set activeUser object  there. like that `statement.setString(1, activeUser );`

Comment: Yes, I need to create somethink like you wrote "activeUser".
But how to create script to check user from session ? I used this basic tutorial to create registration and login: 

http://javaknowledge.info/login-and-registration-example-in-jsp-with-session/

Comment: `request.getSession().getAttribute(attributeName)` this command takes some attribute value from session by specified name. The easiest way is to create some parameter (userID or userName) for current logged user in session and then use it during session.

Comment: Aha, like this? http://s30.postimg.org/4b6dyz0xt/V_st_i_ek.jpg

Is possible to add me on skype please?

Comment: sorry man. I don't have skype at home. but I recommend you to read and even use this articles for your program [number 1](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/) and [number 2](http://www.javatpoint.com/MVC-in-jsp)

Comment: after you submit loggin page you must have some fields like login, password. you can access them by `request.getParameter(parameterName)` and use this parameters in your sql query. select * from members where userName= ? and password=?.

Comment: OK, im going to read.

http://s13.postimg.org/cv1ebomnr/V_st_i_ek.jpg

Its my login script.